# Access denied on pandas to_parquet python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dir structure

```
data
   data1
      year
         month
codes
   extract_data
       historical_data
          script.py
```

When I run `df.to_parquet('C:\users\john\data\data1\year\month')` I get `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Failed to open local file 'C:\users\john\data\data1\year\month'. Detail: [Windows error 5] Access denied.`

I'm running the script from `C:\users\john\codes\extract_data\historical_data\`

I tried to use `C:\\users\\john\\data\\data1\\year\\month` and `r'C:\users\john\data\data1\year\month'` as path, but with no success.

Comment: It seems like a directory. Not a file

Comment: The target path is not available or it could be directory not a file. or You don't have proper permissions. You could run it as administrator.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, can you post your comment as an answer? So I can accept is as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have provided **folder** as the argument for `path`. You must provide the complete filename as `path` instead.

```
df.to_parquet(r'C:\users\john\data\data1\year\month/your_file_name.parquet')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your Python code does not have any necessary permissions to write to the directory that you have mentioned. Try running your script as an administrator.

Comment: It is not a permission issue, I just added the file name in to_parquuet and it worked, `df.to_parquet('C:\users\john\data\data1\year\month\file.parquet')`